# One column figure blocks text in adjacent column

Tags: floats, two-column

I am facing this strange problem where a figure in one column of a two-column page is blocking the second column. In other words, text is not going there in other column with a figure in the adjacent column. This happens only when the figure happens to be on top of a page. Any clues?

Comment: Are you using `figure` or `figure*`?

Comment: I am using figure. I am aware of figure* but I need to save space to accomodate more text which is why I am using figure and the issue is that it's not serving its purpose.

Comment: Without the MWE (requested by Kurt) is hard to provide effective help; I tried to reproduce your problem with some simple test but I wasn't able. Please add to your question the requested MWE.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The problem was solved by one of our collaborators in his edit. I did not pay much attention to it after that. So, am not sure which answer to accept. Community help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen when using the `dblfloatfix` package. I'm not sure *why* this happens though.

Here's a minimal working example that causes the error for me:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{times}

\newcommand{\putfig}{
  \begin{figure}[htb]
  \rule{\linewidth}{4cm}
  \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\putfig
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1-2]
\putfig
\lipsum[1-2]
\putfig
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Maybe somebody else can elaborate on the cause of this. But please check whether you include that package and whether that might be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem, but had been using the `stfloats` package to serve the purpose of `dblfloatfix` (i.e. elsewhere in the document, I wanted a double column float at the bottom of the page).

I then added `dblfloatfix` and the text blocking problem went away (but now with compiler warnings).

I then removed `stfloats` and now the compiler told me I needed to remove the `fix2col` package.

I removed the `fix2col` package and everything seemed to work fine.

Perhaps some of these steps will help someone else with this problem.

Comment: Removing `strfloats` worked for me.  Thanks!